# C++ Code removes first character from vector to int conversion

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, integer, stdvector

Below is my code, CP Code represents a template.
For sometime, I have been trying to figure out why the function `splitStringOutInt` removes the first character. For example, the input is `11 12 13`, but the output is `[1, 12, 13]`. I am very lost, also I am new to C++ so if there is a better method to convert a string line input to an array/vector, please let me know.

```
// START CP CODE
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string cinLine()
{
    cin.ignore();
    string tempVar {};
    getline(cin, tempVar);
    return tempVar;
}

long long int stringToInt(string num)
{
    long long int convertedVal = 0;
    stringstream strConverterOBJ;
    strConverterOBJ << num;
    strConverterOBJ >> convertedVal;
    return convertedVal;
}

int printIntVector(vector<long long int> lst)
{
    cout << "[";
    for(int i=0; i<lst.size(); i++){
        if(i!=lst.size()-1) {
            cout << lst.at(i) << ", ";
        }else{
            cout << lst.at(i);
        }
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;
    return 0;
}

string printStrVector(vector<string> lst)
{
    for(int i=0; i<lst.size(); i++){
        if(i!=lst.size()-1) {
            cout << lst.at(i) << endl;
        }else{
            cout << lst.at(i);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

vector<long long int> splitStringOutInt(char divider, string str)
{
    vector<long long int> intList;
    for(long long int j=0; j<=str.length(); j++){
        long long int answer {};
        if(str[j] == divider || j == str.length()){
            answer = stringToInt(str.substr(0, j+1));
            str.erase(0,j+1);
            intList.insert(intList.end(), answer);
            j=0;
        }
    }
    return intList;
}

// END CP CODE

int main()
{
    vector<long long int> inp1;
    inp1 = splitStringOutInt(' ', cinLine());
    printIntVector(inp1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Print the string out right after you read it. I think you'll find that `cin.ignore();` is what is eating the first character.

Comment: Great!, It worked, I just removed ```cin.ignore();``` I though I used to have a problem when I removed it, but it works fine for now, thanks!

Comment: Usually the only reason you need `ignore` is if you're mixing `getline` and `>>`. You need the `ignore` right after `>>` to consume the newline character. You can avoid this by always using `getline` and using `>>` from a `stringstream` constructed with the line input.

Comment: That really does make sense now, thank you!